# Can I know some good sites to get quality icons?

Tags: vector, icons

I am in middle of developing a software and I couldn't get quality high pixel icons. Hope You guys will guide me with this.

I tried various sites and searched for them and couldn't accomplish the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Deviant Art, Tumblr, Twitter...I mean, there's an entire pixel art community out there that would probably jump at the chance to help you with custom icons! If you don't mind the extra work, MSPaint is always a quick way to set up something.

I'm including an article link here with a bunch of additional, more specific options. Good Luck!

https://www.engadget.com/2016-05-19-18-best-websites-to-download-free-icons-for-commercial-use.html